Is the file structure of a basic RISC-V GNU toolchain project used elsewhere? Where does it originate from?
First, I want to sincerely apologize, because I feel like what I'm about to ask is pretty stupid, and something really basic is flying over my head, but I am at my witts' end.
I've been successfully using riscv32-unknown-elf from the RISC-V GNU toolchain, given that someone else set it up and provided me with a project template. But I have a lot of basic questions, especially related to the file structure of a basic project: how to use the memmap file, what does novectors.s do, how is the information in main.bin different from main.elf, how do all of these files interact with each other etc. But I am unable to find an explanation to my questions while looking for RISC-V GNU toolchain - related information.
Is it correct to assume that the file structure used by a RISC-V GNU toolchain project is used more widely than just by this toolchain? If so, what are its origins, maybe it even has a name (or keywords) I could use to find more information about it?

This question is in need of refocusing to avoid being overly broad and being off-topic: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"
